# Search MySQL database via HTML form through PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've been struggling for a while, trying to figure out how to connect the following query with the HTML search form.

Query:

```
<?php
    include_once("mysqli_connection.php");

    // startpage
    $page = 0;
    //items pr page
    $per_page= 8;
    //smileyscore
    $smiley_score='';

    // perform database query
    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query .="FROM smile AS a, smiley_detail AS b ";
    $query .= "WHERE a.smiley_id = b.smiley_id AND b.smiley >= 1 ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY b.date ";
    $query .= "LIMIT ". $page.', '. $per_page . ";";

    $result = mysqli_query($connnetion, $query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

    $rows = $row[0];

    if (!$result){
        die("database query failed.");
    }
?>
```

Form:

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <form  class="menu" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" id="searchfor" method="post">
                <select type="value"  name="smiley_score" placeholder="s">
                    <option value="0">Alle stikprøver (0)</option>
                    <option value="1">Ingen anmærkninger (1)</option>
                    <option value="2">Indskærpelse (2)</option>
                    <option value="3">Påbud eller forbud (3)</option>
                    <option value="4">Bødeforlæg, politianmeldelse, autorisation eller registrering frataget (4)</option>
                </select>

                <select type="text"  name="city">
                    <option value="">By</option>
                    <option value="København">København</option>
                    <option value="Århus">Århus</option>
                    <option value="Odense">Odense</option>
                    <option value="Alle de andre">Alle de andre</option>
                </select>

                <select type="value"   name="year">
                    <option value="">År</option>
                    <option value="2001">2001</option>
                    <option value="2002">2002</option>
                    <option value="2003">2003</option>
                    <option value="2004">2004</option>
                    <option value="2005">2005</option>
                    <option value="2006">2006</option>
                    <option value="2007">2007</option>
                    <option value="2008">2008</option>
                    <option value="2009">2009</option>
                    <option value="2010">2010</option>
                    <option value="2011">2011</option>
                    <option value="2012">2012</option>
                    <option value="2013">2013</option>
                    <option value="2014">2014</option>
                    <option value="2015">2015</option>
                </select>

                <input type="text" name="searchcriteria" class="form-control" placeholder="Indtast søgekriterier">    </input>
                <button  class="btn" id="submit_button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> Søg</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Echo:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php 
                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    // output data from each row
                    echo '<div class="col-md-12">';
                        echo '<div class="overskrift">';
                            echo '<h3>';
                                echo $row["organisation"] . "<br/>";
                            echo '</h3>';
                            echo 'Branche: '.$row["type"] . " - ";
                            echo 'Dato: '. $row["date"] . " <br /> ";
                        echo '</div >';
                        echo '<p class="adress">';                       
                            echo $row["adresse1"] . "<br /> ";
                            echo $row["zip"] . "  ";
                            echo $row["postby"] . " ";
                            echo '<img class="score" src="img/'.$row["smiley"] .'.gif">';
                        echo '</p> ';
                        echo '<div class="textfield" >';
                            echo $row["text"] . "<br />";
                        echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                // release data
                mysqli_free_result($result);        
            ?>     
        </div>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: where did you get the code?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: regarding where I got the code?? well I wrote it while slowly learning the syntax :-s

Regarding where I was getting stuck. I had huge problems comprehending the relations between the form and the query. turns out the solution was really simple. Thanks for the rapid reply :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could do this. On the page containing the form a pseudo structure like the following might be the answer.

```
<html>
    <head><title>Searches and results....</title><head>
    <body>
    <?php
        if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' ){
            /* Display the form here */
        } elseif( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ) {
            /* Construct and run the sql query */

            /* Display the results here */

        } else {
            /* Wrong method - warn user or redirect or whatever */
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need process the data, you can get the data on the submited form by adding logic that uses the $_POST associative array to your $PHP_SELF, the name of the form element is what is used in array.

For example if you have an element named data, the PHP to access it would be $_POST['data'].

Answer (score 0):

Make a condition in array form. Change the method as get method .
Customize your query like this

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smile  WHERE smiley_id LIKE '%$_GET[term]%' LIMIT $page,$_GET[results]");
```